# "Couldn't reach some vertices" issue looking for shortest path in graphs

Tags: r, sql-server, graph, shortest-path, vertices

I am looking for the shortest paths in 2 different graphs. I did it in R using the `igraph` library and the `shortest.paths` function, then I managed to do the same running R code in SQL Server.

With the following graph it works fine and returns the shortest path from A to E:

[image]

But with the following graph something fails, going from A to G, though using the same code:

[image]

In this case, I get no errors, just a warning message:

> "In .Call("R_igraph_get_shortest_paths", graph, as.igraph.vs(graph,  :
>     At structural_properties.c:4517 :Couldn't reach some vertices"

Both graphs are solved correctly in R finding the shortest path, but the second one doesn't work well in SQL Server and I don't understand why.

Here I add the weighted graphs:

[image: Good]
[image: Bad]

Here is the code I use. I use `v = v[-1]` and `~v = head(v,-1)` because I already know first and last node and just want to know to middle ones.

`library(igraph);`
`row.names(inp) = names(inp);`
`m = as.matrix(inp);` 
`trasp = t(m);`
`gr = graph.adjacency(trasp, mode = "directed", weighted = T);` 
`s = shortest_paths(gr, from = "A", to = "G");` 
`v = as.vector(s$vpath[[1]]);`
`v = v[-1];`
`v = head(v,-1);`
`seq = names(inp)[v];`
`out = data.frame(seq)`

Thanks for your help!

Nick

Comment: Do you have scripts to allow someone to reproduce your issue on their own server?

Comment: Sure. It follows. The input table is a normal simple table 7x7 uploaded from an Excel file, giving the weight of the step between nodes using 0 if nodes are not matched. I use `v = v[-1]` and `v = head(v,-1)` because I already know first and last node and just want to know to middle ones.

`library(igraph);
row.names(inp) = names(inp);
m = as.matrix(inp);
trasp = t(m);
gr = graph.adjacency(trasp, mode = "directed", weighted = T);
s = shortest_paths(gr, from = "A", to = "G");
v = as.vector(s$vpath[[1]]);
v = v[-1];
v = head(v,-1);
seq = names(inp)[v];


out = data.frame(seq)`

Comment: You'd better add the code properly formatted to the question, instead of adding it as a comment. This makes it more legible to us.